# about a simple program

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to this and I am wondering if this is correct. name is supposed to be represented as a `String`, yob as an 4 digit number, state as a `String`, and citizen as a `Boolean`. Now I need to design a class named `Individual` that represents the information above. After I need to make an example, in a class named `ExamplesIndiv`. The example should be an object named david that represents 
David Gerald, born in 1983, from RI, and is not a citizen.

```
public class Individual { 

  String name; 
  int yob; 
  String state; 
  boolean citizen; 

  Person (String n, int y, String s, boolean c){ 
    this.name = n; 
    this.yob = y; 
    this.state= s; 
    this.citizen= c; 
  } 



  class ExamplesIndiv{ 
  //example for david

    Person david = new Person( "David Gerald", 1983, "RI", false); 
  }
}
```

I want to make sure is this what I am supposed to do? Can someone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: Your compiler will tell you: does this code compile (no)? Look at the name of your constructor and the class. You know, if the code doesn't compile, please **tell us**. We're not very good as your substitute compiler.

Comment: Also check your curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class is named `Individual`, creating a Constructor with the Name `Person` will not work. I suspect, that your IDE (and your Compiler) will mark this line containing an error. Reading and unterstanding Compiler Errors is very important, since it is the first hint if something is wrong. In the future, if you post a question, you should really post the Compiler Errors, otherwise people will not be able (or willing) to help.

edit: deleted second paragraph, since it seems that you are supposed to do just that?
Still need to change `Person` to `Individual`. Alternatively you could rename `Individual` to `Person`.